# How to load data dynamically using to API in Multiple UITableView and CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3

Wanted to load data using to api in collection view and table view.

The Table View is going to handle vertical scrolling. Each genre (Week Days) is a table section that contains one header and one cell. The key really is to nest a Collection View inside the Table View row. Just remember to point the Collection View DataSource to the table cell rather than the View Controller, and everything will be just fine.

Following code has been implemented
Controller - TimetableVC
In the controller showing static data ..

```
import UIKit

class TimetableVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     var categories = \["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"\]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
//              return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories\[section\]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow

        return cell
    }

}
```

CategoryRow:

```
// Collectionview data showing

import UIKit

class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

   // var Array = [String]()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // add no of item in the table like 2,3,5
        return 10
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
//        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
//        return cell

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! VideoCell

        var Label1 =  cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        Label1.text = "Subject"

        var Label2 =  cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        Label2.text = "Teacher"

        var Label3 =  cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        Label3.text = "Time"


        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        //cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item] 
//        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project

        return cell

    }    


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 0
        //        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        //        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        let itemWidth = 100
        let itemHeight = 100
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }

}
```

Note: Please help me. I have implemented table view and collection view. I want to show dynamically table header with collection view data using to api response.

Output:

[image: App view]